# I don't understand this circuit intended for 'Spark Excitation' (for use in spectrophotometry)

Tags: spark

I'm buiding a spectrophotometer for elemental analysis of rocks, minerals etc.

The optical part of the spectrophotometer is proving quite uneventful but in order to 'see' any elements in the sample these elements need to be 'excited' in order to observe their *atomic  emission spectrum*. This excitation thermal is usually done thermally (strongly heating the sample)

Googling for an affordable and OTC/DIY solution to the thermal excitation problem, I came across [this useful resource](https://www.ursusmajor.ch/downloads/emission-spectroscopy-2.0.pdf).

Photo from that text:

[image: Excitation]

Unfortunately, due to a poor description in the text, combined with my ineptitude on electrics/electronics, I cannot make heads nor tails of the proposed circuit. What are the parts and how do they connect to provide a source of thermal excitation of the sample?

All help much appreciated...

Comment: The link to the source of those photos gives a description of what the grey thing is. What exactly is your issue? If you buy one and experiment with it, you'll soon see what it does. It has a power input, and high voltage output, there's little more to say about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be trying to replicate this thing:

[image]

Specifically, the part circled in red.

The white thing is just a plastic container - almost anything will do.

The black thing with a red button on it is the entire heart of the "spark exciter."  It is nothing more than the piezoelectric igniter from a gas fired barbecue grill.  You push the button, the crystal flexes, a short pulse of high voltage electricity appears on the wires.

Here's the entire "circuit" from inside the white container:

[image]

The piezo button (red arrow) has two wires.  They go to two jacks into which you can plug wires from the outside.

The wires go to the spectroscopy setup.  That's the grey container.

The spectroscopy chamber has two graphite electrodes:

[image]

The electrodes are marked with red arrows.

Push the button, and a spark jumps between the two electrodes.  If you cover the lower electrode with some material (salt, for example) then the spark will vaporize the salt so that you can see its spectrum.

The circuit is trivially simple:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZKzYb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It only looks complicated because there are a couple of boxes involved and a bunch of wires.  The complications are only there to make it easier to use for different tasks.  It is easier to rearrange it for different materials that way.

---

Be careful using this thing.  It generates a very high voltage.  It can't really kill you because it doesn't generate much energy, but the zaps can be quite painful - I've been zapped by a poorly insulated igniter.

Make sure that the electrodes are close enough together that the spark can jump the gap.  That voltage has to go somewhere.  If it can't jump the gap, it might find it easier to jump through your finger.

Comment: Thank you! Would thick, well insulated gloves protect against zapping voltage? Or is that 'overkill'?

Comment: Every bare conductor (including the graphite electrodes) can potentially zap you.  Rubber gloves would probably be a good idea.  The piezo igniters are usually enclosed in a metal barbecue grill, where the spark would rather jump to the shell than through you.  With everything in plastic and some wiring exposed, a bit of extra insulation won't hurt.  The zap can't injure you, really.  It is just really unpleasant.

Comment: thanks! Rubber gloves it is then.